# WhatsAppAPI Sending Messages And Registering

Tags: whatsapp

I'm just curious as everything I've researched online so far doesn't seem up to date. This weekend I set myself a little project just to automate a message but not spamming or used for commercial use.

I tried to find the password needed for the whatsapp api

```
  WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(myNumber, password, nickname, true);
```

WhatsAppAPI constructor below.

```
 public class WhatsApp : WhatsSendBase
{
    public WhatsApp(string phoneNum, string imei, string nick, bool debug = false, bool hidden = false);
```

The problem and questions I face start with a program called WART which is downloadable from the below github repository.

https://github.com/mgp25/WART

After downloading this and trying to get the password I was unsuccessful. I then used the webclient version.

the github repository stated

> In case WART isn't working, use this online tool:
>   http://watools.es/pwd.html

To my surprise WhatsApp have blocked my number. From responses online I didn't think anyone else has had this problem.

I was aware that I could be blocked for spamming but I didn't send one message through he API and so I'm slightly confused.

Is there away round this?
Is this not a suitable project? 
Have I done something wrong? 
Has anyone used this API before?

Edited Recently after more research to add the below...

Just found this repository that was taken down [WhatsAPI Repository](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI)

From the looks of it WhatsApp was targetting spammers .
[Why Was WhatsAPI ShutDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520776/is-it-legal-to-use-whatsapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhatsApp have informed me that they have detected that the verification code was not sent from a mobile device and have blocked the account. So I can only assume that WART isn't a suitable registration application for getting your whats app password any more and I'll have to see this as a failed project.

Anyone else's experiences or knowledge would still be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: WART is giving a Bad_Token error while requesting code. Don't know if it is because the number is blocked or any other reason